# jquery on page load slidedown div with height set to auto

Tags: jquery, height, slidedown

I have a div where the height is set to auto since the site is responsive.  This seems to break the slidedown function.  Is there a way to have the div figure out the height and then slidedown?  This seems to be a question a lot of people have yet I have not found an answer.  Can some genius here help out?

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you could just use the [.height();](http://api.jquery.com/height/)
function to get the current height of the selected element, without any more code it's hard to help you out any further. And you can use the [resize();](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function to make it run